# Scripts contained in the package have compilation errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

In my developer environment(Visual Studio/SSDT 2013) I created a ssis-package with a script-task.

But when I try to open the package on the production environment(Visual Studio 2010/SSDT 2010) I get "compilation errors" on the script-task. I haven't made any changes in the code, I also tried to replicate the original on a new script-task, inside of SSDT 2012, with copy-paste. Just needed to change the namespace, and add a new Web Reference(which is needed to get data from the web-api), based on the original from the developer environment.

Also when I build the script it succeeds, but gives me a compilation error when I save and quit and press "OK".

Why is that? Does "C# 2010"´really differ that much from "C# 2012" so it could be a difference in code/library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the web reference. When i add a new script-task and leave the default code in it's fine. Later on i added just a web-reference and it got me the compilation error. Any suggestions?

Comment: When i change Build from debug to release and press "Build" it shows me this error message.  "Error 1 Task could not find "sgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed ST_c3e73f41c5334af0b4b99a86cb33c786"

Comment: which led me to this solution: http://www.igloocoder.com/2015/09/17/Task-could-not-find-sgen-exe-using-the-SdkToolsPath/

Comment: If you solved the issue. Why not writing an answer and accepting it. So the question is marked as answered